# Best way to maintain a list of values in Java

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a class that holds a list of connected clients, with their usernames being the key and the client instance being the value. So far the class looks like this:

```
public class ClientList {

    private static HashMap<String, Client> clients = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Add a client to the list of connected clients
     *
     * @param username Unique client key
     * @param client The client to add to the list
     */
    public static void add(String username, Client client) {
        clients.put(username, client);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a client from the list
     *
     * @param username the client to remove
     */
    public static void remove(String username) {
        clients.remove(username);
    }

    /**
     * Get the client in the list that has the given username
     *
     * @param username The username of the client to return
     * @return The client with a matching username
     */
    public static Client getClient(String username) {
        return clients.get(username);
    }

    /**
     * @return The client list
     */
    public static HashMap<String, Client> getList() {
        return clients;
    }

}
```

However, upon review of the class I realised all of these methods are simply passing params to the `HashMap` class, meaning the `ClientList` class brings nothing new to the program. Now because of that, I know I could just create a static `HashMap<String, Client>` somewhere and use that without having to create a whole new class for it; my issue is I don't have any suitable classes to store the list in, for example for my `ClientListener` class to access the list I do not want to have to statically access a class with an irrelevant name, such as     `ClientWriter.clientList`. So my question is, what is the best way of handling this map where it maintains suitable readability?

Comment: First of all, stop using `static` where you don't need it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The client list is static because I do not want to be creating any new instances of it. What approach should I take instead of this?

Comment: _I do not want to be creating any new instances of it_ is not a good reason not to be creating new instances of it.

Comment: Which if your classes use this client information?  That would be a place to start in where to put it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I do not want to be creating new instances of it because I need to ensure all classes that access and change it are accessing and changing the same instance and not creating their own copies of the client list. So again, if not this, what approach do you recommend?

Comment: @user949300 Various classes related to the Client class. the Client class itself also uses it for its disconnect method, but it did not seem suitable as lots of different threads create instances of the Client class

Comment: What exactly the purpose of the structure?

Comment: @nikpon To maintain a list of clients and their corresponding usernames. It being a HashMap means I can get clients by their username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: This seems a good idea.  Until your application is wildly successful and you need to support "free" clients and "premium" clients.  Or you support multiple sockets, FTP and HTTP, security levels, whatever.  At that time you might regret a Singleton.